# Good way to select multiple rows with non-scalar list of keys using Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF 4 and I'm trying to find a good way to select records where the primary key uses multiple columns and using a list of objects to search from.  Here's what I've tried so far with no luck:

I have a list of objects of type Foo.  Foo has two properties, A and B.  The primary key on the Order table is columns A and B.

```
var orders = (from o in context.Orders
              where FooList.Contains(new Foo { A = o.A, B = o.B }
              select o);
```

This throws an error that I can only use a scalar value.  From what I can tell, I would need the FooList to be a list of scalars.  I've also tried to join with my object list, but that didn't work either:

```
var orders = (from o in context.Orders
              join foo in FooList
              on new { foo.A, foo.B } equals new { o.A, o.B }
              select o)
```

Obviously, I could just iterate through all of the values in FooList, get the order that I need and update it, but this is extremely slow in my current situation (about 6000 values in FooList).

Any ideas?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Someone has to have an answer for this.... I am going to start playing around with EF to look for a solution

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to use (a variant on) [the BuildContainsExpression workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/) which was necessary before EF 4.

The resulting SQL will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to "scalarify" your composite key in the query to map the key to a unique scalar. For example: Say, your properties `A` and `B` were strings:

```
var orders = (from o in context.Orders
              where FooList.Select(f => f.A + ";" + f.B)
                  .Contains(o.A + ";" + o.B)
              select o);
```

(This scalar is generally not guaranteed to be unique, of course, but it might still be fine if you know that your strings `A` and `B` never can contain a semicolon.) You have to take care that the expression in `Contains` can be translated into SQL (which would work in this example of string concatenation).

Comment: That defeats indexing, though.

Answer (score 0):

We should be able to accomplish this by modifying the expression tree. Effectively we want to translate the expression tree into sql like this:

```
Where
(
   (Foo.A == "A" && foo.B == 1)
|| (Foo.A == "B" && foo.B == 2)
)
```

So if we use the Contains syntax and under the covers use expression visitor to go through the tree and replace the expression, we should get what we want.

Unfortunately, I don't have enough in depth knowledge of the LINQ expression trees to come up with a solution quickly.

Most of the examples I have seen deal strictly with modifying the expression tree to deal with scalar values (List.Contains) or using the expression tree to generate their own SQL for bulk operation execution.